# Order of multi column index in rails polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have a table with a polymorphic reference that I generated via the following migration:

```
def change                  
  add_reference :table_name, :thing, polymorphic: true, index: true
end
```

When I ran the migration it generated the following:

```
add_index "workflow_engine_task_bases", ["thing_type", "thing_id"], name: "index_workflow_engine_task_bases_on_thing_type_and_thing_id", using: :btree
```

Why is the left-most column the thing_type? To me it seems that this is suboptimal as it is less specific.

Answer (score 12):

This is the [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9cdd0a1fdf8308985231242d378e3a1c29c4ab00) in Rails by Derek Prior that updates `add_reference` to use `type` before `id` when generating an index for a polymorphic association. The justification for the change is reproduced below:

> **Use type column first in multi-column indexes**
>
> `add_reference` can very helpfully add a multi-column index when you use
>   it to add a polymorphic reference. However, the first column in the
>   index is the `id` column, which is less than ideal.
>
> The [PostgreSQL docs][1] say:
>
> A multicolumn B-tree index can be used with query conditions that
>   involve any subset of the index's columns, but the index is most
>   efficient when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost)
>   columns.
>
> The [MySQL docs][2] say:
>
> MySQL can use multiple-column indexes for queries that test all the
>   columns in the index, or queries that test just the first column, the
>   first two columns, the first three columns, and so on. If you specify
>   the columns in the right order in the index definition, a single
>   composite index can speed up several kinds of queries on the same
>   table.
>
> In a polymorphic relationship, the type column is much more likely to be
>   useful as the first column in an index than the id column. That is, I'm
>   more likely to query on type without an id than I am to query on id
>   without a type.
>
> [1]: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-multicolumn.html
>
> [2]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

I think in most scenarios, this order makes sense. It allows you to have a single index that performs well on queries including `type` and `id` or just `type`.

Having said that, your use case may vary depending on the database you use, your dataset, and what queries you plan to run. Your best bet is to profile your most common use cases on a production dump and choose your indexing strategy accordingly.

Comment: I'm not clear how to reconcile this with the advice given in Percona’s article, “[Choosing Column Order in Indexes](https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/06/05/a-rule-of-thumb-for-choosing-column-order-in-indexes/),” which is to prioritize the most **selective** columns (the ones that will most reduce the number of matches) -- in technical terms, the column with highest **cardinality**.  

Since the cardinality of `thing_type` is so low (both absolutely and _relative_ to `thing_id`), then if we query exclusively by type the index wouldn’t be useful, AFAICT.  Better to optimize querying by both.

Answer (score 0):

From http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_reference.

In the source code for `add_reference`:

`add_index(table_name, polymorphic ? [type id].map{ |t| "#{ref_name}_#{t}" } : "#{ref_name}_id", index_options.is_a?(Hash) ? index_options : {}) if index_options`

It's just mapping from an array where `type` is ahead of `id`. Not sure why it was designed this way, but it might be better to just use `add_index` instead.

`add_index(:table, [:thing_id, :thing_type])`